# Set up a Java OAuth Provider

Tags: java, oauth, provider

So, I am trying to set up an OAuth Provider in Java, but I just cannot get the hang of it.
Everywhere I look I'm always redirected here (http://oauth.net/code) but there's no documentation.
Could someone help me out, step by step, or reference me to a more direct guide? I'm even having trouble building the library. Can anyone help me please? Thank you very much.

Comment: The page you refer to contains Java libraries that you can use to your help. But you will have to understand the OAuth specification fully to implement a provider yourself. That's just the name of the game. The answers below both have good resources for improving your understanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer http://oauth.net/core/1.0a

To learn the workflow, refer http://hueniverse.com/oauth/guide/workflow/ and the Appendix A of the document.

Then chapters 3 and 4 to learn of all entities. For the actual workflow, read chapters 6 and 7 with their respective appendix entries.

Chapter 10 is a handy debug thing.

---

I guess you need to implement the datastore yourself, and I dont envy you :-)

Learn from the datastore for Oauth-PHP library . http://code.google.com/p/oauth-php/source/browse/trunk/library/store/mysql/mysql.sql . Refer all the `oauth_server_*` tables to get an idea of how to store data for an OAuth provider.

---

OAuth server and client libraries should abstract the rest.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest Spring Security OAuth for this kind of tasks.

You have two sample projects [there](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples):

- sparklr - provider
- tonr - consumer

Maybe the best way to learn would be investigating source code.

You can find additional info [there](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-security-oauth/wiki/oauth1)...